# A consequence of Gauss' lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

The following is written in Fulton's Algebraic curves book but I can't quite understand it.

> If $R$ is a UFD with quotient field $K$, then (by Gauss) any
>   irreducible element $F\in R[X]$ remains irreducible when considered in
>   $K[X]$; **it follows that if $F$ and $G$ are polynomials in $R[X]$ with
>   no common factors in $R[X]$, they have no commmon factors in $K[X]$.**

I understand Gauss' Lemma, but I can't see how it implies the sentence in boldface.

Comment: What happens if you decompose your polynomials as irreducible factors in $R[X]$ ?

Comment: @Max What do you mean?

Comment: Write $F,G$ as products of irreducibles : what does it mean to say that they have no common factors in $R[X]$ ?

Comment: @Max It means the irreducible factors of $F$ and $G$ in $R[X]$ are distinct.

Comment: @Max I think I got it. Since the factorization in $K[X]$ is unique, this factorization in $R[X]$ is also the factorization in $K[X]$, so the irrreducible factors of $F$ and $G$ in $K[X]$ are distinct as well. Is this it?

Comment: $K= Frac(R)$ is a field so $K[X]$ is a UFD and $F(X)=  \prod_j F_j(X)^{e_j}\in K[X]$ so for some $c \in R$ you have the factorization $c^{\sum_j e_j} F(X) =  \prod_j (cF_j(X))^{e_j}\in R[X]$. But it is very possible that $F(X)$ is irreducible in $R[X]$, only $c^{\sum_j e_j} F(X) $ is reducible : try with $R = \mathbb{Z}[2i], f(X) = X^2+1 \in R[X]$, also note $X^2+1,2X+2i$ have no common factor. To avoid that possibility, assume that $R$ is a UFD, then (Gauss lemma) the $F_j(X)$ are automatically in $R[X]$ and you don't need to multiply by $c^{\sum_j e_j} $ anymore.

Comment: @reuns we are already assuming $R$ is a UFD.

Comment: @Max could you please check what I wrote?

Comment: As I said at first you are just assuming $R$ is integral domain and $K= Frac(R)$ is a field. You deduce the factorization in $K[X]$ and in $R[X]$, the latter involves an annoying constant  term. Then you see how Gauss lemma simplifies it when $R$ is an UFD.

Comment: @reuns thus, summing up, the factorizations of F and G in R[X] and K[X] are the same by Gauss lemma, since F and G don't have a common irreducible factor in R[X], they also don't have a common irreducible factor in K[X]. Is this it?